# customizing sample of countdown timer

Tags: javascript

i need to add a script to page, which will create a countdown timer for a specified date.
I will change a date in script by cmd batch file so it will be configurable.

i have a script as bellow but it create a countdown with moths, days, minutes and sec. And i think that seconds is configured as "--" (so i will need to change it to at least three digits number / so in script i think that change cl.secs.value="--" to cl.secs.value="---" will make a job.).

```
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var eventdate = new Date("December 25, 2013 23:59:59");

function toSt(n) {
 s=""
 if(n<10) s+="0"
 return s+n.toString();
}

function countdown() {
 cl=document.clock;
 d=new Date();
 count=Math.floor((eventdate.getTime()-d.getTime())/1000);
 if(count<=0)
   {cl.days.value ="----";
    cl.hours.value="--";
    cl.mins.value="--";
    cl.secs.value="--";
    return;
  }
 cl.secs.value=toSt(count%60);
 count=Math.floor(count/60);
 cl.mins.value=toSt(count%60);
 count=Math.floor(count/60);
 cl.hours.value=toSt(count%24);
 count=Math.floor(count/24);
 cl.days.value=count;    

 setTimeout("countdown()",500);
}
// end hiding script-->
</SCRIPT>
```

So i really dummy with scripting and im sure that can take me a long time to customize according my needs. Can you help me please? :)

Or can you give me a simple example of javascript (i just need a javascript var as  countdown number and by call in a form wil give me a countdown.)

Answer (score 0):

here is the countdown plug-in.I have used many time before.Try to use this

[countdown plugin](https://github.com/kbwood/countdown/blob/master/countdownBasic.html)

[example here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)